# Is there a better and cleaner way to write this two functions?

Tags: java, collections, iterator

So I am struggling to write this code in a clean way. I do not know if there is a better way.

```
private function1(Collection<D> collection) {
    for (Iterator it = collection.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Object object = it.next();
        switch (object .getClass().getSimpleName()) {
            case "A": do some work with class A
                break;
            case "B": do some work with class B
                break; 
            case "C": do some work with class C
                break;  
        }
    }
}
```

So I get a collection which I iterate. But the collection can be three different classes in the collection since class A,B,C are of the parent class D. I think my code is not clean and I am looking for a good way to write this. Here is another example that I have which is a bit different.

```
private function2(Collection<A,B,C> collection) {
    for (Iterator it = collection.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Object object = it.next();
        switch (object .getClass().getSimpleName()) {
            case "A": do some work with class A
                break;
            case "B": do some work with class B
                break; 
            case "C": do some work with class C
                break;  
        }
    }
}
```

In this function I can get either a collection of class A of class B or of class C. I though about making three separate functions for each class. But than I would have code duplicates. But I don't know if it would be actually better to split function2 into function2A, function2B, function2C.

Is there a better and cleaner way to implement those two functions. Classes A,B,C and D are from a framework. So I am unable to edit them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an interface that A, B, and C can implement from. In your interface you can declare a method that will 'do the work' and A,B, and C can have their own implementations.

```
interface MyInterface{
  void doTheWork();
}
```

Then do this for each class

```
class A implements MyInterface { 
    void doTheWork() { 
        ...
    } 
}
```

Now you can just loop through the collection without having to check what class the instance is of

---

**EDIT** - If you cannot modify A,B, or C than you can use a map with the class as the key and a lambda as the value.

```
//pseudocode
Map<Class<?>,Runnable> lambdaClassMap = new HashMap<>();
lambdaClassMap.put(A.class, () -> doAWork());
lambdaClassMap.put(B.class, () -> doBWork());
lambdaClassMap.put(C.class, () -> doCWork());

for(...) {
    Object object = it.next();
    lambdaClassMap.get(object.getClass()).run();
}
```

---

**EDIT #2** - So since you want to access your object, instead of using `Runnable` you can use `Function`.

```
// change the function do what you want
// this one accepts the A object and calls an imaginary method 'getSize()'
Function<A, Integer> funcA = x -> x.getSize();

Map<Class<?>,Function> functionClassMap = new HashMap<>();
functionClassMap.put(A.class, funcA));
```

Now, you can use the `apply()` method on your function to access your object directly when you are looping.

```
Integer size = functionClassMap.get(object.getClass()).apply(object);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This would work great. I forgot to add that the classes I am using are in a jar file. So I am not really able to edit them. Any idea how that changes up things?

Comment: I've updated my answer with another way of doing things since you cannot modify those classes

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :) left out the most important part of the problem

Comment: one more question :) I am struggling to find a way to do it. But if I wanted to put parameters from the object into these dowork functions. How would I do it?

Comment: @TenebrisNocte updated my post again with a solution for that :)

Comment: @Holger lol that is a much better idea, I've updated my post to use `Function`

Comment: I don’t think that it is a good idea to map `A.class` to a function that expects `String` as input.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize polymorphism to avoid the need to determine which subclass it is for the purpose of doing different work for each class.

Add a method `doWork` (or whatever name you have that would be more appropriate) to the `D` superclass, and implement it in all the subclasses `A`, `B`, and `C`.  It may be `abstract` in `D` if appropriate.

Then your method becomes the following:

```
private void function1(Collection<? extends D> collection) {
    for (Iterator<? extends D> it = collection.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        D d = it.next();
        d.doWork();
    }
}
```

Use `? extends D` so that the method can accept a `Collection<D>`, `Collection<A>`, `Collection<B>`, or `Collection<C>`.  This also avoids the raw `Iterator`.

You can also use the equivalent, shorter, enhanced for loop:

```
private void function1(Collection<? extends D> collection) {
    for (D d : collection) {
        d.doWork();
    }
}
```

Your second method appears just like the first method except that it attempts to use a `Collection<A, B, C>`, which doesn't make sense.  `Collection` has only one type parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This would work great. I forgot to add that the classes I am using are in a jar file. So I am not really able to edit them. Any idea how that changes up things?

Comment: That is an important detail you originally left out.  If the classes are in some other library you're using and you can't edit them, hopefully they're not `final` and you can subclass them.  Then create an interface for the `doWork` method, create subclasses of the 3 classes A, B, and C, and have your subclasses implement the interface.  Then the interface name replaces `D` above.  If they're final, then you'll need wrapper classes instead of subclasses.

Comment: Yes that would be an option. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea.  Mainly it separates the list of classes to process from the calling method so you don't have to modify your switch method to add other classes. Note that Collections implement `Iterable` so you don't need an explicit iterator.

It also presumes you would have methods established to do the required work.

- build a map of name to method to call.  This part replaces your switch statement.
- it uses a default method to catch unknown class names should they appear
- it them simply iterates, processing the objects.

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class WorkFunction {
    Map<String, Consumer<Object>> fnc = Map.of(
              "A", this::doWorkA,
              "B", this::doWorkB,
              "C", this::doWorkC);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         WorkFunction wf = new WorkFunction();
         
         List<Object> list = List.of(new A(), new B(), new A(), new A(),
                                     new C(), new B(), wf);
         
         wf.function1(list);
    }
      
    static class A {}
    static class B {}
    static class C {}

        public <D> void function1(Collection<D> collection) {
             for(D object : collection) {
                  fnc.getOrDefault(object.getClass().getSimpleName(), 
                           (ob)->System.out.println("Who are you??")))
                  .accept(object);
               }
         }
        
        public void doWorkA(Object ob) {
            System.out.println("Working on A");
        }
        public void doWorkB(Object ob) {
            System.out.println("Working on B");         
        }
        public void doWorkC(Object ob){
            System.out.println("Working on C");
        }
        
}
```

prints

```
Working on A
Working on B
Working on A
Working on A
Working on C
Working on B
Who are you??
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help :)